# Route Azure Service Bus traffic over ExpressRoute?

Tags: routing, azure, ip-routing, url-routing

Azure Service Bus exposes a publicly addressable HTTPS endpoint. For security reasons we'd like to force Service Bus traffic from on-prem systems to Azure over Express Route rather than over the public Internet.

How can we do that? Is there a way to configure either Azure Service Bus or Express Route to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to look at your express route configuration. Express route has 3 routing domains:

- Private Peering - This connects your network up to IaaS resources in your specified vNets, likely what you have in place now
- Public Peering - This routes all traffic for Azure resources with public URL's over Express Route, this is what you will need to get your service bus access to route over Express Route
- Microsoft Peering - This adds in things like Office 365 to the Express Route connection

You'll need to look at getting public peering enabled to get our public Azure URLS to go over Express Route. Take a look at [this document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/expressroute-circuit-peerings/) for more details.